# Mercurial Workflow (Shared Files)

Tags: mercurial, workflow

Let's say I have programmers and artists working on a project.  The artists have some folders they care about:

```
/Doodles
/Images/Jpgs
```

And maybe the programmers have a folder like this:

```
/Code/View/Jpgs
```

What is the best process in Mercurial to keep the 2 Jpgs folders synced?  I have used Vault, where you can have 2 or more files/folders linked in a repository so updating one updates another.  Is there a way to do the same thing with Mercurial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could be managed through JPgs as a [**Mercurial Subrepo**](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos), that is as a nested respository managed by both programmers and artists, in their own respective main projects.

Comment: I gave it a try, but I get this error when I try to commit in the sample:
   `hg: config error at .hgsub:2: ' '`
Any idea?

Comment: @Jake: seems related to a syntax error in the hg config file. You need to try it out in a small independent main project/subrepo and play with it a little before applying that to the JPegs directory.